# Find Recurring Outlook Events Happening Today

Tags: ruby, outlook, ole

I have a Ruby script using Win32OLE to read through my Outlook events and find events ocurring today (based on the Start date value).

```
events_today = ''

calendar.Items.each do |appointment|
    appt_date = Time.parse(appointment.Start)
    if appt_date > today && appt_date < tomorrow
        events_today << "<p><strong>#{appointment.Subject}:</strong> #{appt_date.strftime("%I:%M %p")}</p>"
    end
end
```

It catches one-time events that occur today, but it doesn't seem to catch recurring events (ie, events that started last week and occur daily including today).

Is there better field to use to search for the event (other than `appointment.Start`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Items.IncludeRecurrences property:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171434(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: That's just what I needed, thanks! (A note for anyone else trying this, be sure to do a `.Sort("[Start]")` before the call to `IncludeRecurrences`. That tripped me up a bit.